# Unreachable code detected in public method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm receiving an "Unreachable code detected" warning near the end of the following
method at:

```
return RedirectToAction("WorkspaceHome", "Workspace");
```

Any ideas about how I can solve this issue? Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Delete_Task_Project(int id)
{
    using (ctx_TaskCollab.TaskCollab tkContext = new ctx_TaskCollab.TaskCollab())
    {
      //get the task 
      ctx_TaskCollab.Task taskToBeDeleted = tkContext.Tasks.Where(x=>x.Task_PK == id).Single();

      //check if the task is being deleted by the owner 
      if (taskToBeDeleted.CreatedBy == User.Identity.Name.ToLower())
      {
          //if the task is a project then delete the subtasks and the project.
          if (taskToBeDeleted.TaskParent_FK == null)
          {
              //get all the subtasks 
              List<ctx_TaskCollab.Task> tasksToBeDeleted = tkContext.Tasks.Where(x=>x.TaskParent_FK == id).ToList();

              foreach (var item in tasksToBeDeleted)
              {
                  item.IsDeleted = true;
              }
              taskToBeDeleted.IsDeleted = true;
              tkContext.SaveChanges();
              return RedirectToAction("WorkspaceHome", "Workspace", new { view="Projects"});
          }
          else { //delete the task
              taskToBeDeleted.IsDeleted = true;
              tkContext.SaveChanges();
              return RedirectToAction("WorkspaceHome", "Workspace", new { view="Tasks"});
          }
          //If the id is a project, delete the project and the tasks.
      }
      else 
          return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized","Errors");
    }                
    return RedirectToAction("WorkspaceHome", "Workspace");
}
```

Comment: Can you find a path through the code that will reach the last `return` statement?

Comment: All paths of your code have a return statement, so you can never reach that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final return statement:

```
return RedirectToAction("WorkspaceHome", "Workspace");
```

Will never execute, because there is no code path before it that does not return something else first.  Remove this statement to silence the warning.

To elaborate, here is the simplified structure of your method:

```
using {
    if {
        if {
            return; // 1
        } else {
            return; // 2
        }
    } else {
        return; // 3
    }
}
return; // 4
```

You cannot get to return statement number 4 without first passing through one of the other three.  The compiler has correctly deduced that there is no circumstance in which the fourth return statement would execute, and hence it is "unreachable."  Unreachable code wastes space (if it even gets emitted during compilation -- it can be optimized away) and usually indicates an error on the part of the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `if` with an `else` there is no third way, that's why the code after the `using` is never executed. You can simplify it in this way to see what i mean:

```
using (var foo = SomeDisposable)
{
    if (SomCondition)
    {
        if (SomeOtherCodition)
        {
            return SomeThing;
        }
        else
        { 
            return SomethingElse;
        }
    }
    else
        return HereAllCasesAreHandled;
}
// following code is in the void because it can never be executed:
return RedirectToAction("WorkspaceHome", "Workspace");
```

So the compiler wants to help to fix this bug. Remove the redundant code or change the logic.